# Fedora 15 , unable to install programmes

Tags: mysql, package, fedora

this is my first post, so lets get into it:

my problem is with fedora 15

```
# uname -a
Linux alienware 2.6.38.8-35.fc15.i686 #1 SMP Wed Jul 6 14:46:26 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

and with installation of some programmes I have this kind of thing going on:

```
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.10-2.fc15.i686 (fedora)
           Requires: mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.10-2.fc15
           Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.14-2.fc15.i686 (@updates)
               mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.14-2.fc15
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.10-2.fc15.i686 (fedora)
               mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.10-2.fc15
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.10-2.fc15.i686 (fedora)
           Requires: mysql(x86-32) = 5.5.10-2.fc15
           Installed: mysql-5.5.14-2.fc15.i686 (@updates)
               mysql(x86-32) = 5.5.14-2.fc15
           Available: mysql-5.5.10-2.fc15.i686 (fedora)
               mysql(x86-32) = 5.5.10-2.fc15
```

from the message it seems, that I am kind of ahead, but what to do with it, I encountered it also on many others, but this one is the most recent one and I desperately need this. Please someone help me to solve this.

(I have tryed some things from the internet, but wont work at all... and reinstal is not the solution either.... what now ? :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried installing the dependancies first?

```
yum install mysql-libs-5.5.10-2.fc15 mysql-5.5.10-2.fc15
```

Then:

```
yum install mysql-server-5.5.10-2.fc15
```